# What is Staging directory in Kubernetes for?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm still new to Kubernetes and I'm wondering why and what codes go into [Kubernetes staging directory](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/66674f549626cc41f04e475d2c0e865116c4cd40/staging) there is a description there in README file but I'm not sure what does that mean?

Comment: This seems like it's a part of the Kubernetes build system, and not necessarily something a normal Kubernetes user or application developer would need to worry about.  What led you to this directory?

Answer (score 0):

As the README states:

> This directory is the staging area for packages that have been split to their own repository. The content here will be periodically published to respective top-level k8s.io repositories.

Kubernetes uses a mono-repo to store all the code for its components. Some of these code exist in separate repositories too e.g. [kube-proxy configuration api](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-proxy). The code for these packages is maintained in the `staging` directory and periodically synced to the external repositories.